# How to find shortest path between one source and all the remaining vertices?

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, undirected-graph

I use the function `g.get_shortest_paths(vertex_index)` to get all shortest paths between one source vertex_index and all the remaining vertice, but this function doesn't take the constraint on the returned path.

I have a graph `G` and a set of vertices `N`, I need to get all shortest paths between one vertex source `s` and all the other vertices in `G` where all paths don't contain any vertices from `N`.

Comment: Remove the N vertices from G and run shortest path on the remainder.

Comment: Learn Dijkstra or Topo Sort or Bellman Ford.